# Start a New Page with PDFKit including Table headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit in Rails that displays records of table from my db. I want to display the new page continue to the records and also with table headers when the current page has no space. How can I achieve this?

```
    html_content = render_to_string(:template => "example/pdf_example.html.erb",:layout => false)
    pdf_convert = PDFKit.new(html_content, :margin_right => '0.1in',:margin_left => '0.1in',:margin_top => '0.1in',:margin_bottom => "0.1in",:page_size => "A4", :orientation => 'landscape')

    report_name = "example report"
    send_data(pdf_convert.to_pdf,:filename=>"#{report_name}.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "wicked_pdf" which will convert html page to pdf with all html style.

```
<% if params[:format] == "html"%>
  <%= render template: "reports/term_loan_report_data_header.html.erb"%>
<%end%>
```